# AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voice is fred's voice in iOS 12 if no voice identifier is set.

Tags: ios12

AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voice is fred's voice in iOS 12 if no voice identifier is set. How can we go back to default voice?

Comment: why it is marked down?

Comment: similar issue is reported here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52727301/ios-text-to-speech-what-decides-the-default-voice-returned-by-avspeechsynthesi.

Answer (score 0):

com.apple.ttsbundle.Samantha-compact is the default voice from AVSpeechSynthesisVoice. This is how you can go back to default voice-

```
AVSpeechSynthesisVoice* voice = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithIdentifier:@"com.apple.ttsbundle.Samantha-compact"];
```